# Lightweight thread-safe persistent queue for Java

Tags: library, java

I'm looking for some fast lightweight thread-safe implementation of a persistent queue which can be easily embedded into a Java service. Something like https://github.com/bulldog2011/bigqueue but with JDK 11 support. Are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seem to be a patch for JDK 11 on one of the issues against that project, perhaps you can fork it?